# check inserted value in excel?

Tags: excel

I wanna check inserted value in excel cell and if value is higher than something(for example 3000)
excel don't accept value(also throw error).
So how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the cells you want to validate, then choose Data → Validation. In the new dialog, choose:

- Allow: Whole number / Decimal
- Data: Less than
- Maximum: 3000

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/211485 for detail.